# Where are some good online covid 19 genetic datasets?

Tags: research, covid19, genome

I want to carry out some research with covid19 genetic datasets that include people infected by corona virus and people that aren't infected by it. Does anybody know any good ones? My main purpose is diagnostics of a genome to detect a possible infection.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Do you want human genomes or virus genomes? If human, do you want both humans who are testing negative and who are testing positive?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I would like human genomes that test negative and positive for comparing. But I think I made myself completely clear in the question ...

Comment: Sorry! I accepted the wrong one. My mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one resource

**https://www.covid19hg.org/**

> The COVID-19 host genetics initiative brings together the human genetics community to generate, share and analyze data to learn the genetic determinants of COVID-19 susceptibility, severity and outcomes. Such discoveries could help to generate hypotheses for drug repurposing, identify individuals at unusually high or low risk, and contribute to global knowledge of the biology of SARS-CoV-2 infection and disease.

Not sure exactly where the raw data is -- but maybe this "results" page, which has "Download" links on the bottom: https://www.covid19hg.org/results/

Answer (score 2):

There is a large body of research and data around COVID-19. Help the global community better understand the disease by getting involved on Kaggle.

[Datasets in Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=covid%20in%3Adatasets) related to COVID

Popular datasets

- [COVID-19 Open Research Dataset Challenge (CORD-19)](https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge?select=document_parses)
- [UNCOVER COVID-19 Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/roche-data-science-coalition/uncover)

Comment: The question asks for genome datasets, your answer does not attempt to answer that. Please find more specific datasets, thanks!